# The image in the drawable folder does not appear in the list while adding as background

Tags: android, drawable

["background.jpg" and "background_chat.png" don't appear in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhKNV.png)

I'm still trying to learn Android Studio and faced a problem that I could not understand. I put the pictures in drawable folder but can't use them. What's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
you can restart your android studio

Under **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**